# Application of QFT to Order-finding

Tags: quantum-algorithms, textbook-and-exercises, nielsen-and-chuang, quantum-fourier-transform, order-finding

In the Nielsen & Chuang book, section 5.3.1 page 226, there is a statement which goes like this:- (**statement-1)**

> The quantum algorithm for order-finding is just the phase estimation
> algorithm applied to the unitary operator
> $U|y\rangle ≡ |xy(mod N)\rangle$

Well, this statement is not a trivial one. And then one more,
(**statement-2**)
(Eqn 5.37) defines the eigenstates of the unitary operator $U$ as:

> $$|u_s\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{r}}\sum_{k=0}^{r-1}\exp\left(\frac{-2\pi isk}{r}\right)\left|x^k\text{ mod } N\right\rangle \text{ for integer } 0 \leq s \leq r-1$$

Now, there are two questions:

1. How do we know **statement-1**? How do we know that the unitary operator which we have defined here, would give us the solution to the order finding problem?
2. How do we arrive at **statement-2**? Eigenstates of $U$ are just the eigenvectors of $U$, so somebody might have calculated them, right? (For example, by solving $U-\lambda I= 0$). However, I don't see how one would arrive at something so elegant. Or is it just some of those "define" statements?

I would be glad if I get an answer to any of these questions.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "this" in "How do we know this? and "that" in "How do we arrive at that?" in your questions?

Comment: The calculation which proves that the states $|u_s\rangle$ defined by $(5.37)$ are the eigenvectors of $U$ is given in $(5.38)$ and $(5.39)$ on the same page. Is the step from $(5.38)$ to $(5.39)$ unclear or is there some other question here?

Comment: @Condo I am sorry that I posed in such a way. Let me rephrase it.

Comment: @AdamZalcman.: No that part is clear, but let's suppose I tell you "how do you know that the state would be what is shown here?" What is the answer for that?

Comment: @Condo Hello. I have edited it out. Now it is more clear.

Comment: I think all this is more out of necessity than anything, in the sense that the only advantageous thing that you can do on a quantum computer is essentially phase estimation of a unitary operator. I'm not sure the formula for the eigenstates is so much elegance than it is simply a fact... unitaries are a rather restrictive set of operations, especially in this context.

Comment: @Condo But tell me one thing, this statement doesn't surprise you? `The quantum algorithm for order-finding is just the phase estimation algorithm applied to the unitary operator U|y⟩≡|xy(modN)⟩` How did they find it? I mean how can I even intuitively explain it to someone if they ask me, "hey so how do you know this is the answer to order finding?" Because then I need to show the states `u_{s}` and then they will again ask the same question..."how did you find it?"

Comment: @user27286 Well firstly things aren't discovered the way they are laid out in a textbook. Shor's original paper on polynomial-time factoring actually used a slightly different method to order finding on a quantum computer, the method mentioned in N&C is due to Kitaev... I don't think there is an easy answer to your question but perhaps you can start here https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/9903071.pdf

Answer (score 5):

**Answer to question 1**

There are many ways the first quantum algorithm for order finding could have been conceived and I don't know how it really happened. However, here is a plausible though entirely fictional account of how one might have arrived at it:

**Alice:** Hey, I was imagining doing arithmetic on a quantum computer and made a unitary that computes multiplication modulo a given integer $N$.
**Bob:** Hey, that's cool! What is it?
**Alice:** Well, it really just permutes the computational basis states like this
$$
U|y\rangle = |xy\pmod N\rangle\tag1
$$

when $x$ and $y$ are coprime to $N$ and acts as identity otherwise.
**Bob:** Right. I wonder what $U$'s eigenvalues are...

*See the answer to question 2 below for details of what occurs here. Some time later:*

**Alice:** So the eigenvalues are $\exp\frac{2\pi i s}{r}$ for $s=0,\dots,r-1$ where $r$ is the order of $x$ modulo $N$.
**Bob:** Interesting... Wait, what?!... We can use the Quantum Phase Estimation algorithm to compute eigenvalues of any unitary. This means we could use QPE to find $r$!
**Alice:** You're right! Wasn't finding $r$ supposed to be computationally hard?
**Bob:** On a *classical* computer? As far as we know, yeah.
**Alice:** Looks like it's computationally easy on a quantum computer!

---

**Answer to question 2**

As in question 1, there are many ways one can arrive at the result. The following elementary approach is loosely inspired by the [power iteration algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_iteration) for finding eigenvectors and eigenvalues. Note that if $|v\rangle$ is an eigenvector of $U$ associated with eigenvalue $\lambda$ then

$$
U^k|v\rangle = \lambda^k|v\rangle.
$$

However, from the definition of $U$ in $(1)$ we know that

$$
U^k|y\rangle = |x^k y\pmod N\rangle
$$

for a computational basis state $|y\rangle$ encoding a $y$ coprime to $N$. Now, let $r$ be the order of $x$ modulo $N$, i.e. $x^r = 1\pmod N$. Then,

$$
\lambda^r|v\rangle = U^r|v\rangle = |v\rangle
$$

and we see that $\lambda$ is a number such that

$$
\lambda^r = 1.
$$

In other words, the eigenvalues are the $r$th [roots of unity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity)

$$
\lambda = \exp\frac{2\pi i s}{r}\tag2
$$

for $s = 0,\dots,r-1$.

Having found the eigenvalues, we now want to find the corresponding eigenvectors. We begin with the observation that $U$ permutes the states $|x^0\pmod N\rangle,\dots|x^{r-1}\pmod N\rangle$. Consequently, the uniform superposition

$$
|v_0\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{r}}\sum_{k=0}^{r-1}|x^k\pmod N\rangle\tag3
$$

is an eigenvector associated with eigenvalue $1$. Hoping that $(3)$ might be a special case of a more general pattern, we next try

$$
|v_{a_0,\dots,a_{r-1}}\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{r}}\sum_{k=0}^{r-1}a_k|x^k\pmod N\rangle\tag4
$$

for some complex numbers $a_0,\dots,a_{r-1}$. If we apply $U$ to both sides of $(4)$, we get

$$
U|v_{a_0,\dots,a_{r-1}}\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{r}}\sum_{k=0}^{r-1}a_k|x^{k+1}\pmod N\rangle
$$

which shifts the kets by one position cyclically relative to the coefficients $a_k$. However, by definition of eigenvector, we need this reshuffling to allow us to pull a constant out in front of the sum, so we see that we need $a_k = a^k$ for some constant $a$, i.e.

$$
|v_a\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{r}}\sum_{k=0}^{r-1}a^k|x^k\pmod N\rangle.
$$

Let us try it

$$
\begin{align}
U|v_a\rangle &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{r}}\sum_{k=0}^{r-1}a^k|x^{k+1}\pmod N\rangle \\
&= a^{-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{r}}\sum_{k=0}^{r-1}a^{k+1}|x^{k+1}\pmod N\rangle
\end{align}
$$

so if $a^r=1$ then

$$
\begin{align}
U|v_a\rangle &= a^{-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{r}}\sum_{k=0}^{r-1}a^{k+1}|x^{k+1}\pmod N\rangle \\
&= a^{-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{r}}\sum_{k=0}^{r-1}a^k|x^k\pmod N\rangle \\
&= a^{-1} |v_a\rangle
\end{align}
$$

and $|v_a\rangle$ is an eigenvector associated with eigenvalue $\lambda = a^{-1}$. This is reassuring, because it means that our assumption that $a^r=1$ is satisfied. It also means that $a = \exp\left(-\frac{2\pi i s}{r}\right)$. Putting it all together, we see that

$$
|u_s\rangle = |v_{e^{-2\pi is/r}}\rangle = \sum_{k=0}^{r-1}\exp\left(-\frac{2\pi isk}{r}\right)|x^k \pmod N\rangle
$$

is an eigenvector of $U$ associated with eigenvalue $\exp\left(\frac{2\pi i s}{r}\right)$ in agreement with $(5.37)$ on p.227 in Nielsen & Chuang.

Comment: Thanks. It helps.